# Can I use shape.width as condition in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use the width of  shape as condition in a if. My code below is automatically adding numbers to shapes in range of cells.

```
Sub numShapeMasqueD()

    Dim shapeTemp As Shape
    Dim masqueD As Range
    Dim cpt As Integer
    Dim row As Long, col As Long
    Set masqueD = Range("h22:r31")
    cpt = 1

    For row = 1 To masqueD.Rows.Count
        For col = 1 To masqueD.Columns.Count 
            For Each shapeTemp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
                If Not Intersect(masqueD.Cells(row, col), shapeTemp.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
                        shapeTemp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = cpt 
                        cpt = cpt + 1
                End If
            Next shapeTemp
        Next col
    Next row

End Sub
```

I tried using `shapeTemp.width` as conditon in an If. What I want to do is if width of shapeTemp is below **12.97016** then set `shapeTemp.TextFrame.Characters.Font = 8`.

I hope I explained my problem clearly.

Comment: You declare shapeTemp but never set it. You might also want to Round the width.

Comment: @Jeeped Well I'm starting to learn VBA by myself. So I'm not sure why I need to set shapeTemp, as I use it in bigger code and it works fine. Can  you explain me why I should do so ?

Comment: @LyessD `Dim` declares the variable. `Set` assigns it. Until it's assigned, the value of the variable is a null object reference, aka `Nothing` - and making member calls against `Nothing` will throw run-time error 91.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I undestand now. However why do you want me to assign this object variable, I don't want to give it a value.

Comment: If you don't assign shapeTemp, it is `Nothing`. How do you get the width of `Nothing`?

Comment: @VincentG I understand what you say, I edited my post.

Comment: You new code explain the context better, but should also contain the test lines. Note that if you want to test ***below*** 12.97016, you need to use `If shapeTemp.Width < 12.97016 Then`, not `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead,

Why don't you make another variable and set the value to ShapeTemp.Width
Also like jeeped commented, you need to actually declare shapeTemp.

```
Dim shapeTemp as Shape
Dim shapeWidth as Double

shapeWidth = shapeTemp.Width

If shapeWidth = 12.907016 then
   shapeTemp.TextFrame.Characters.Font = 8
End If
```

Comment: I don't get it. If you want to use `set` to declare shapeTemp you need to make `shapeTemp = 'something'` right ? I don't undestand why it is usefull to me here ?

Comment: An `Integer` can't have a value of `12.907016`, it's an *integer* type.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks for pointing that out. I have made the changes above.

Comment: @LyessD in this instance you have declared a variable and not specified what it is.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I use shapeTemp in a loop over Activesheet.Shapes . This is why I don't set shapeTemp. Should I edit my post with the entire method ?

Answer (score 0):

You declared the local variable `shapeTemp`, but you did not set it to anything. You need to set `shapeTemp` to something. Here is more information about the scope of variables in VBA:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/141693/scope-of-variables-in-visual-basic-for-applications

There are examples below of how to set `shapeTemp`.

To create a new shape:

```
Set shpTemp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 10, 10, 100, 100)
```

To retrieve the first shape that already exists in the shapes collection:

```
Set shpTemp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
```

You can also set shpTemp to another existing shape, or you could pass a shape object into your procedure using a parameter/argument.